# If an Ancient Metallic Dragon uses Change Shape to turn into a humanoid with Innate Spellcasting, do the uses of “X/day” spells reset each time?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph, dragons, spellcasting

Ancient Metallic Dragons (e.g. [Ancient Brass Dragons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ancient-brass-dragon)) have the Change Shape ability:

> ***Change Shape.*** The dragon magically polymorphs into a humanoid or beast that has a challenge rating no higher than its own, or back into its true form. It reverts to its true form if it dies. Any equipment it is wearing or carrying is absorbed or borne by the new form (the dragon's choice).
>
> In a new form, the dragon retains its alignment, hit points, Hit Dice, ability to speak, proficiencies, Legendary Resistance, lair actions, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores, as well as this action. Its statistics and capabilities are otherwise replaced by those of the new form, except any class features or legendary actions of that form.

It is my understanding that the Spellcasting feature is a class feature and thus unavailable to an Ancient Metallic Dragon, but that the Innate Spellcasting trait is available to them.

Now, let’s take in example the [Gloom Weaver](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/gloom-weaver) humanoid from *Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes* (p. 224), who has the following not-at-will Innate Spells:

> 1/day each: *arcane gate*, *bane*, *compulsion*, *confusion*, *true seeing*

If, say, an Ancient Brass Dragon decides to use Change Shape to turn into a Gloom Weaver, then decides to cast its 1/day *true seeing*, then uses Change Shape to revert to their dragon form, and uses it yet again to become a Gloom Weaver once more... does the dragon thus have a new use of *true seeing*?

In other words, does an ancient metallic dragon have essentially unlimited “X/day” innate spells by way of using Change Shape back and forth?

Comment: Are you asking as the DM, or as the player?

Answer (score 5):

### No, you have to rest to be able to use them again

MM 11:

> **X/Day.** The notation "X/Day" means special ability can be used X number of times and and that a monster must finish a long rest to regain expended uses. For example "1/Day" means a special ability can be used once and that the monster must finish a long rest to use it again

So if it is the same monster and the same ability you can use it only after a long rest.

Is it the same monster? Yes - the change shape only replaces statistics and capabilities not the monster identity.

Is it the same ability? Yes  - you are using exactly the same text block, and the fact that you temporarily lost this ability while in dragon form does not change that fact any more than walking through anti-magic field does.

---

And if you are wondering if you can circumvent this to another creature that can cast the same spells, the answer is still no, because both the monster and the ability is still the same.

Comment: While I think this is a ruling I would make I don't think it is supported by any actual rules.