# If a dragon under my control uses Change Shape to turn into an Evoker, can I choose the Evoker's race, and benefit from its racial traits?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, polymorph, racial-traits, shapeshifting

Nuanced questions about True Polymorph and spellcasting:

I have a wizard who has a simulacrum. Wizard TP's the sim into an adult bronze dragon, which can then Change Shape into a humanoid or beast of its CR or below. TP says the sim retains personality and alignment, so it still holds loyalty to me. I have it transform into, say, an Evoker (CR 9 humanoid wizard with spellcasting prepared).

---

If my dragon-sim changes shape into said Evoker, which has no default race, am I able to choose the race of the Evoker and grant it those racial traits (ex. Halfling Luck, Warforged Resilience, etc.)?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. We generally have a [policy of one question - or very closely related set of questions - per post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6453/33569). As such, you may want to edit this question down to focus on a single issue, and ask your other questions separately. (#1 is a single distinct question; #2 is a separate one. #3-4 is another question related to #2. #5 is a separate question, and so is #6.) It'd be hard for a single answer to meaningfully address all of these points at once.

Comment: #5 is almost a duplicate of this question: [If an Ancient Metallic Dragon uses Change Shape to turn into a humanoid with Innate Spellcasting, do the uses of “X/day” spells reset each time?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152885/if-an-ancient-metallic-dragon-uses-change-shape-to-turn-into-a-humanoid-with-inn)

Comment: Related but non dupe: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/144387/can-a-simulacrum-true-polymorphed-into-an-archmage-regain-spell-slots

Comment: Apologies, very new here. At least to posting, that is. Thought it'd be easier to lump all of them in together considering they regard the same topic - True Polymorphing into a creature that can change its shape into a spellcasting being.

On the topic of #5, you're correct. I'll edit that one out.

Comment: Edited down again and split questions up for clearer answers.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, you can choose the race.

Per the description of the Change Shape Action, you can choose any humanoid or beast, and therefore "Halfling Evoker" or "Warforged Evoker" are certainly eligible options.

### No, you cannot grant it those racial traits.

Belonging to a race does not inherently attribute features. For example, not all Yuan-ti have *Magic Resistance*. While common features are present on many members of a race, a creature only has the features included on its stat block, as per the *Change Shape* description:

> Its statistics and capabilities are otherwise replaced by those of the new form, except any class features or legendary actions of that form.

In this case, the relevant stat block is that of the [Evoker](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/evoker). The only features included are *Spellcasting* and *Sculpt Spells* regardles of which race you chose for your change shape.

### Well, that just sounds like slavery with extra steps

For clarification, there is little difference between Change Shape and directly Polymorphing your Simulacrum into the Evoker, though I do understand the reusable benefit of TPing the Sim into a dragon. In both cases, the new stat block becomes prevalent except where specified otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

An 'Evoker' is just a wizard (Medium humanoid (any race), any alignment) trained in the arcane arts via their class.

The spell specifically states that you can't gain class features. As for proof that this is in fact a class feature it actually says they're wizard spells.

> The evoker is a 12th-level spellcaster. Its spellcasting ability is
>   Intelligence (spell save DC 15, +7 to hit with spell attacks). The
>   evoker has the following **wizard** spells prepared:

You can't gain class features, any class features, which definitely includes the class features of being a wizard.

Just because it's labled as a specific thing in the monster manual doesn't mean it's a creature you can polymorph into. An Evoker is not a creature. It's a description of a person with class features. You're quite literally trying to gain class features. This is exploitative and unacceptable. It goes against the intent of the spell and the rules as written.

Comment: Can you support that you can't TP into an evoker? You say it's against RAW and RAI, but you don't actually support those statements. Not saying you're wrong, just that you need to back it up. After all, many monsters state they are "X level spellcaster" like the [arcanoloth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/arcanaloth-summoner-variant).

Comment: @NautArch The entry itself says that it's not a specific creature, it's a class template you can apply to any race. You don't shapechange into a class template and then later pick a convenient race. That's wrong from top to bottom.

Comment: [Related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/144387/can-a-simulacrum-true-polymorphed-into-an-archmage-regain-spell-slots) that seems to disagree. If you can add support to yours, then you've got other questions to answer :)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Agree on removing how they'd rule (unless they've done/seen it  and how the players responded to back it up), but the  RAW and RAI statements of not allowed need to be supported.

Comment: I'd point out that the NPCs are in a separate appendix.  they are not in the actual monster list.  It might be pointed out that misc creatures are also in an appendix, but those are specifically called creatures in the appendix title.